# The Stack Exchange homepage doesn't have any questions on it

Tags: bug, hot-questions, homepage

Something seems terribly wrong here. All of the questions are missing from the Stack Exchange homepage. What's going on?

[image: Blank homepage]

Comment: No repro. Try again.

Comment: ...and it's fixed now. That was weird. I did refresh the page multiple times and stuff, but I guess it was a momentary outage.

Comment: Probably due to: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1315808005095600129